# How to have a custom bodyLimit for a single api when using fastify with openapi

Tags: openapi, fastify

I am using fastify with openapi from nodejs with the modules

openapiGlue & fastify

I'd like one specific route to have a non-default body limit.  Is this possible ?  I tried the following in my api.json definition

```
    "/api/myApi": {
      "post": {
        "x-fastify-config": {
          "bodyLimit":10000000
        }
     ...
```

but this does not work.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I could not find a way to do it from the openapi JSON file ... but ... it can be done with an onRoute hook which is run as openapi JSON is parsed.

```
fastify.addHook('onRoute', (routeOptions) => {
  if (routeOptions.path === 'mypath') {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(routeOptions));
    routeOptions.bodyLimit=10000000
  }
});
```